# git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, deployment, nested-forms, production

I have deployed my application on linux server with passenger and apache, I have done bundle install run successfully still i get
( `git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run bundle install (Bundler::GitError)` ) error while i try to run my application

FYI, i am using rails 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3

This works fine on my development machine

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have currently solved the issue by running below

`bundle pack` 
`bundle install --path vendor/cache`

This solves my problem, but it stores whole gems in the vendor directory

But still if anybody have better solution then please let me know

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I always installed my gems as system-wide gems (including the ones from github).

```
$ sudo bundle install
```

When I ran rails, I got the same error:

```
$ rails s
http://github.com/Sija/garb.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

So when I ran:

```
$ bundle install
```

This installed the gems from github locally, but otherwise used all the other system-wide gems.

Then when I ran rails again, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running bundle install as root? If yes, try running bundle install without "sudo", anyway this seems to be a permissions problem (as Google suggests [google => (at master) is not checked out. Please run bundle install (Bundler::GitError)])[1](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/213962)

Comment: I have run it without sudo, and even it shows me in the gem list, it is also shows me if i do bundle show nested_form, So in this case its already checked out from master branch

Comment: myself i rand with sudo, it was in gem list, but command: rails g nested_form:install, generated same error as u had above.